# Merging DataTables where primary key changes

Tags: c#, datatable, merge, primary-key

I've added a row to a datatable, and pass that table (with the new row) to a process that assigns (or changes) the value of the primary key.

When I merge the tables, I want the newly assigned primary key to overwrite the original value.

Stepping back, the records are added to a Client-Side datatable, but the physical table writes are handled by a web service. When the Client adds a record and triggers an update, a dataset with the datatable is passed to a server component.

There the actual insert occurs and with it, a primary key for the record is generated, and server version of the dataset/datatable/datarow is updated to reflect the new primary key.

The dataset/datatable/datarow is passed back to the client and a Merge takes place.

Because the primary keys no longer match, the Client side dataset/datatable maintains two copies of the row.

A lot of the plumbing is handled by the application I'm working with so for example, the actual Merge code I do not see.

However and overall, this type of activity is almost 2nd nature to the application and in many many places, a primary key is created by a server-side component, and the Client side resolves the Merge gracefully.

I gather that something in the rowstate indicates to the Merge process, that a primary key has changed.

Thoughts?

Comment: Create a new field in your datatable to store the original client primary key when the server assigns a new value to the primary key.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I'm hoping instead not to follow that line since the MERGE code, I don't have access to - directly anyway. And regards the "2nd nature" comment, that strategy doesn't appear to be implemented anywhere else.

Comment: What instructions do you use to send datatable updates to server ? What is the principle of your merge function (e.g. compare all records fields except the key to identify duplicates,...) ? The usual strategy for such updates is to operate row by row and at each row insert to get back the primary key from the server. The SQL instruction(s) of the InsertCommand depends on database (Oracle, MySQL, ...).

Comment: The client passes a dataset to the server, i iterate through rows that are modified - which includes the new row with the temporary id - and call a stored procedure to insert the row which is unrelated to the dataset. The stored procedure returns the ID to the c# server-side calling code, where I update the ID (BeginEdit/EndEdit), then pass the dataset back to the client.  The MERGE is handled by the client side and I generally unaware of how it functions.

Comment: Point being, I'm NOT using a DataAdapter.Update(dataset) to push changes to the database. When server receives the dataset, I use it generate a stored procedure call... Once the stored procedure is complete, I update the dataset manually, replacing the temporary key with the "real" key.  From there the dataset is passed back to the client.